# jQuery Table row highlighting query

Tags: jquery, highlight, tablerow

I have the following code:

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered_error');
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
  }).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

This very nicely highlights a table row.  However, I now have more than one table on the same page and I only want the above `highlighting` to work for one of the tables.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Comment: Yes, rather than selecting all tables, only select the one table... `$('#tableid tr:not(:first-child)')`

Comment: give the table a class & use `$('table.myclass tr:not(:first-child)')`?

Comment: Also, if your table has a `tbody`, a far more efficient selector would be `$("#tableid tbody tr")`

Comment: @KevinB - this might sounds backwards but I want it to work the other way around!?

Comment: Yep, that's correct - backwards I know!

Comment: Give the tables you want this to work on a class, and select by that class instead of the id i mentioned. tymeJV's answer shows a good example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the table you want to omit a unique ID (ex `hoverTable`)

```
$('table:not(#hoverTable) tr:not(:first-child)').mouseover(function() {
```

Comment: Hey tymeJV - appreciate the feedback but I actually need it to work the other way - highlight all tables except one.  Odd I know!

Comment: @Homer_J And again, if your table has a tbody, and you give the target tables a common class, a far more efficient selector for this would be: `$(".hoverTable tbody tr")`, primarily because `:not()` is very slow in comparison to not using it.

Comment: @KevinB - noted - appreciate that - had added notes to my code accordingly.